# How to configure read_timeout and open_timeout for Selenium in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm getting this exception when calling `goto()` via Watir:

```
Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:217:in `rbuf_fill'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1509:in `block in transport_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1506:in `catch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1506:in `transport_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1479:in `request'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:129:in `response_for'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `request'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:64:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:567:in `execute'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:59:in `get'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in `to'
    /var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/navigation.rb:16:in `goto'
```

It seems that I can modify the timeouts, but I don't understand how.

They are used [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb), but how do I configure them?

Comment: YMMV: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir#default_timeout-class_method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to [Documentation Ruby-Bindings : Internal timeouts](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#internal-timeouts)

> From Documentation :  Internal timeouts Internally, WebDriver uses
>   HTTP to communicate with a lot of the drivers (the JsonWireProtocol).
>   By default, Net::HTTP from Ruby's standard library is used, which has
>   a default timeout of 60 seconds. If you call e.g. Driver#get,
>   Driver#click on a page that takes more than 60 seconds to load, you'll
>   see a Timeout::Error raised from Net::HTTP. You can configure this
>   timeout (before launching a browser) by doing:

```
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, http_client: client
```

In Watir it may be something like

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome          
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 600 
client.open_timeout = 600 
driver =  Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, 
:http_client => client
```

Comment: `desired_capabilities => caps` is not necessary.